# System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server-2005, asmx, sqldmo

i am using .net webservice for restoring the database in sqlserver. i am using SQLDMO.dll, to restoring database, when i run the app, i getting the following Error.

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. --->  System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {10021CC1-E260-11CF-AE68-00AA004A34D5} failed due to the following error: 80070005.
   at DBReplicatorService.SQLDEMOScripts..ctor()
   at DBReplicatorService.DBReplicatorService.RestoreDB(String sDBName, String sUserName, String sPassword, String sBackupFileName)

i am using the code as follows to connect Database

```
Dim objBCPExport As New SQLDMO.BulkCopy2
Public objDB As SQLDMO.Database2
Dim objServer As New SQLDMO.SQLServer2

Public Function ConnectDatabaseWithRefresh(ByVal sServerName As String, ByVal sDatabaseName As String, ByVal sUserName As String, ByVal sPassword As String) As Boolean
    Dim bResult As Boolean

    Try
        objServer = New SQLDMO.SQLServer2
        objServer.EnableBcp = True
        objServer.Connect(sServerName, sUserName, sPassword)
        objDB = Nothing
        objDB = objServer.Databases.Item(sDatabaseName)
        objDB.DBOption.SelectIntoBulkCopy = True
        bResult = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        bResult = False
    End Try

    Return bResult
End Function
```

same code when i use in my localhost it is working fine(it contains sql server 2005), and when i use it in hosting server(it contains sql server 2008) i getting the above Error

I getting the error in these variable initialization.

```
Dim objBCPExport As New SQLDMO.BulkCopy2
```

and connection string i am using is

```
     Dim cnnNewDB As New SqlConnection("Data Source=" + pServer + "Initial Catalog="    +   pDatabase + ";Persist Security Info=True;User ID=" + pUserName + ";Password=" + pPassword)
```

can any one please help me to fix the problem.

Thanks,
Senthil.

Comment: Warning* I am guessing here :-) Your problem is that most likely the process hosting the web service needs elevated permissions to work with SQLDMO. The identity account on your threadpool is most likely not given access to the required permissions.

Comment: i not connecting database by using 'sa' account, and the account i am using have no rights to create database, is it a problem?

Comment: Please post your connection string, but yes, if you use integrated security then your account needs access to sql server

Comment: Hi, i added the line where i am getting error and connection string.

Answer (score 0):

hey,
if you're sure about the accuracy of user-server name and password
your project may not has right to write the event log..
to fix that go to
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Eventlog\Application\RestrictGuestAccess    and change its value to (0) to reboot